Discrete mathematics: Simulate the probability question
Problem
There are 1, 2, 3, 4 number card in a bag.

If you pick up 1, add one white ball into box_b.
If you pick up 2 or 3, add one white ball and one balck ball into box_b.
If you pick up 4, add two white balls and one black ball into box_b.
You must put the card back in your pocket every time you pull it out.
You have to do this 4 times.

When there are  8 balls in box_b, what is the probability that the number of black balls in the box is 2?
Code
import math

#흰공=0 검은공=1
box_b = list()

#조건부확률 = box_b 원소 개수 8개(=e)이면서 1이 2개(=f)일 확률 / e 확률
cnt_e = 0 
cnt_ef = 0

for i in range(1, 5) : 
    if i == 1 :
        box_b.append(0)
    if i == 2 or i == 3 :
        box_b.append([0, 1])
    if i == 4 :
        box_b.append([0, 0, 1])
    for j in range(1, 5) :
        if j == 1 :
            box_b.append(0)
        if j == 2 or j == 3 :
            box_b.append([0, 1])
        if j == 4 :
            box_b.append([0, 0, 1])
        for k in range(1, 5) :
            if k == 1 :
                box_b.append(0)
            if k == 2 or k == 3 :
                box_b.append([0, 1])
            if k == 4 :
                box_b.append([0, 0, 1])
            for l in range(1, 5) :
                if l == 1 :
                    box_b.append(0)
                if l == 2 or l == 3 :
                    box_b.append([0, 1])
                if l == 4 :
                    box_b.append([0, 0, 1])
                print(box_b)

output
Output should be like [0, [0,1], [0,0,1], [0,1]], [...], but it's output is [0, [0,1], 0, [0,1], 0, [0,1], 0, [0,1] .... (very long list)...] [..]
What's wrong with my code?

My teacher said that the box_b should be reseted when i, j, k, l change. Because of it, the result has been piled up. But he and I don't know which line the reset point should go into.

++ It is not duplicate : I tried i == 2 or i == 3(seperation of two conditions), but it isn't major problem which I look for. There are still problems.

This is how simulating the problem would look like:
import random

random.seed(1)


def calc_prob(bag, sims):
    def pick():
        card = None
        while card is None:
            card = random.choice(bag)
            if card is not None:
                bag[card] = None
                break
        return card

    eights = 0
    blacks = 0
    for _ in range(sims):
        box_b = []
        for _ in range(4):
            card = pick()
            if card == 1:
                box_b.append(0)
            elif card == 2 or card == 3:
                box_b.extend([0, 1])
            elif card == 4:
                box_b.extend([0, 0, 1])

        if len(box_b) == 8:
            eights += 1
            if box_b.count(1) == 2:
                blacks += 1

    return blacks / eights if eights else 0


sims = 100000
bag = [1, 2, 3, 4] * (sims + 1)
print(calc_prob(bag, sims))



Prints
0.08484606447865234

Note:

Every time you pick a card, the card should be removed from the bag and that card is no longer in the "pool" of cards.


The question says "You must put the card back in your pocket every time you pull it out."
Every time I pick a card, the card should be returned and there are 4 card always.

@jinee It means every time one card is picked, that one card  is no longer in the bag. Right? For instance, bag = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 , 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], we pick 4. then the bag would change to: bag = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 , 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]. Its size reduces from 16 to 15.

Well noted. But I still have problem.
First, why we do it 100000 times?(sims) I learn a little bit of python, so I can't understand this despite your kind explanation.
Second, eights should be 70 and blacks should be 6. I tried print(eights,blacks) in your code, but there isn't this value.

@jinee 100000 times are not necessary. Just for averaging the probability. You can post a question here to get a better grasp of fundamentals.

I think the section where you're comparing whether the value is equal to 2 or 3 is not behaving as expected. The python "or" operator works as OR(value on left, value on right), so if you write "i == 2 or 3" this is actually OR(i == 2, 3) and will always return true since the value on the right is greater than 0 and considered True.
It should be "i == 2 or i == 3" instead (which would be OR(i==2,i==3)). Same idea for "k","j", and "l".
Old:
    box_b = list()

for i in range(1, 5) :
    if i == 1 :
        box_b.append(0)
    if i == 2 or 3 :
        box_b.append([0, 1])
    if i == 4 :
        box_b.append([0, 0, 1])
    print(i,box_b)

New:
box_b = list()

for i in range(1, 5) :
    if i == 1 :
        box_b.append(0)
    if i == 2 or i == 3 :
        box_b.append([0, 1])
    if i == 4 :
        box_b.append([0, 0, 1])
    print(i,box_b)


Thank you for answering.
I follow your answer, but there was still same problem.
My teacher said that box_b should be reseted when i, j, k, l change.
But he and I don't know which line the reset point should go into.
